# Remove multiple square brackets using replace() - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a response from the server that is like this:

```
users: ["beautykarttworld","sbdanwar","haiirfavs","show__tanz","kinjal_suhagiya_9999","_adultmafia_"]
```

It's a string not an array like it appear, since I need an array to work on, how I can remove the square backets and then the commas to obtain a normal array?
I've tried in this way:

```
var data = ["beautykarttworld","sbdanwar","haiirfavs","show__tanz","kinjal_suhagiya_9999","_adultmafia_"]
data.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',');
```

but chaining two `.replace()` functions and a `split()` isn't the best solution. Can anyone halp me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `data` is an array.

However, if `data` was a string you would convert it to an array like this:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: I was thinking that it was a string that was returned inside the JSON response. I'm a newbie developer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> In short,
> Here you have provided data in **normal string** formate **not in JSON string formate**
>
> ```js
>  
> var data = 'users: ["beautykarttworld","sbdanwar","haiirfavs","show__tanz","kinjal_suhagiya_9999","_adultmafia_"]'
>  
> var squareBracketData = data.substr(data.indexOf("["))    
> var array = JSON.parse(squareBracketData)
> console.log(array)
> ```
>
> Some personal advice, **Try to send JSON stringify data** from the
> server so it will make your life easy
>
> Example:
>
> ```js
>  
> var users =["beautykarttworld","sbdanwar","haiirfavs","show__tanz","kinjal_suhagiya_9999","_adultmafia_"]
>
> // Stringify data
>
> var data = JSON.stringify({users})
> console.log("Data")
> console.log(data)
>  
> // retrieve data from string
>  
> var parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
> var parsedUsers = parsedData.users
> console.log("parsedUsers")
> console.log(parsedUsers)
> ```